# Mesh contents get flipped

Tags: unity, c#, shaders

I am using below shader with my mesh object that is showing a webpage. It is showing fine but the problem is the web page has flipped:

```
 Shader "UI/Default_OverlayNoZTest"
 {
     Properties
     {
         [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
         _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
         
         _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
         _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
         _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
         _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
         _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255
 
         _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
     }
 
     SubShader
     {
         Tags
         { 
             "Queue"="Overlay" 
             "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
             "RenderType"="Transparent" 
             "PreviewType"="Plane"
             "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
         }
         
         Stencil
         {
             Ref [_Stencil]
             Comp [_StencilComp]
             Pass [_StencilOp] 
             ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
             WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
         }
 
         Cull Off
         Lighting Off
         ZWrite Off
         ZTest Off
         Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
         ColorMask [_ColorMask]
 
         Pass
         {
         CGPROGRAM
             #pragma vertex vert
             #pragma fragment frag
             #include "UnityCG.cginc"
             
             struct appdata_t
             {
                 float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                 float4 color    : COLOR;
                 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
             };
 
             struct v2f
             {
                 float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                 fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                 half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
             };
             
             fixed4 _Color;
 
             v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
             {
                 v2f OUT;
                 OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                 OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
 #ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
                 OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
 #endif
                 OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                 return OUT;
             }
 
             sampler2D _MainTex;
 
             fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
             {
                 half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                 clip (color.a - 0.01);
                 return color;
             }
         ENDCG
         }
     }
 }
```

I am using above shader so that the mesh should be shown on top of everyting.

Comment: Did you consider inverting the texture coordinate? (x or y, depending on which axis it's flipped on)

Comment: How or where to flip ? There is no property on the shader. Let me check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a single line to your vertex shader to invert the texture coordinates.

```
v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
{
     v2f OUT;
     OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
     OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
#ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
     OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
#endif

     // Invert the x coordinate to mirror the texture left/right.
     OUT.texcoord.x = 1.0f - OUT.texcoord.x;

     OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
     return OUT;
}
```

Here I've shown it mirroring on the x. You can use y instead to flip the texture top-to-bottom.

Comment: Thanks, you are always helpful. i also found this in the code    _mainMaterial.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", new Vector2(-1, 1)); but changing its value wasn't helpful

Comment: The reason it wasn't helpful is that your shader is not written to use the texture scale data. You can instead write `OUT.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX (IN.texcoord, _MainTex);` to apply those transformation values to your texture coordinate, using one of Unity's built-in macros for the purpose.